# How do I get subscript in ggplot2 facet grid labels when I have two faceting variables?

Tags: ggplot2, facet, subscript

I am trying to change one of the labels in my facet grid to contain some subscript text. I have been looking on stack overflow but none of the solutions work/I cannot understand how others are functioning so cannot apply them to my own scenario

This is my current ggplot function:

```
FacetGridTest <- tss_profiles %>% group_by(pulldown, Condition, replicate, category) %>%
    group_by(pulldown,Condition,category,region_bin, region) %>%
  mutate(meannone = mean(none)) %>%
  ungroup() %>% 
  mutate(cond_cat=factor(cond_cat, levels=c("IG Target","IG Non-Target","MH Target","PH Target","MH Non-Target","PH Non-Target"))) %>%
   mutate(category=factor(category, levels=c("Target","Non-Target"))) %>%
  ggplot() + aes(x=Bin, y=meannone, col=Condition, group=paste(pulldown, Condition, replicate, category)) +
  geom_line() +
  facet_grid(pulldown~category, scale="free_x") +
  theme_bw(base_size = 10) +
  theme(legend.text.align = 0) +
labs(y=expression(paste("Read Counts")),
     x=expression(paste("Bin"))) + 
  scale_colour_discrete(name = "Condition", labels = c("A","B","C"))  + 
  geom_vline(xintercept=6000, linetype="dotted")  +
  annotate("text", x = 1000, y = 8800, label = "TSS", size=3) +
  annotate("text", x = 11000, y = 8800, label = "TTS", size=3)
```

I want to change the "Non-Target" label to "J<sub>2</sub>L<sub>2</sub> Non-Target<sub>20</sub>+"

Based on what I have seen on stack overflow I have tried doing:

```
vnames <- list('Target' = 'Target',
'Non-Target' = expression(paste("J" ["2"], "L" ["2"], " Non-Target" ["20"], "+")))
bnames <- list('A' = 'A','B' = 'B')

plot_labeller <- function(variable,value){
  if (variable=='category') {
    return(vnames[value])
  } else if (variable=='pulldown') {
    return(bnames[value])
  } else {
    return(as.character(value))
  }
}

tss_profiles %>% group_by(pulldown, Condition, replicate, category) %>%
    group_by(pulldown,Condition,category,region_bin, region) %>%
  mutate(meannone = mean(none)) %>%
  ungroup() %>% 
  mutate(cond_cat=factor(cond_cat, levels=c("IG Target","IG Non-Target","MH Target","PH Target","MH Non-Target","PH Non-Target"))) %>%
   mutate(category=factor(category, levels=c("Target","Non-Target"))) %>%
  ggplot() + aes(x=Bin, y=meannone, col=Condition, group=paste(pulldown, Condition, replicate, category)) +
  geom_line() +
  facet_grid(pulldown~category, scale="free_x", plot_labeller) +
  theme_bw(base_size = 10) +
  theme(legend.text.align = 0) +
labs(y=expression(paste("Read Counts")),
     x=expression(paste("Bin"))) + 
  scale_colour_discrete(name = "Condition", labels = c("A","B","C"))  + 
  geom_vline(xintercept=6000, linetype="dotted")  +
  annotate("text", x = 1000, y = 8800, label = "TSS", size=3) +
  annotate("text", x = 11000, y = 8800, label = "TTS", size=3)
```

But this has not worked. I am probably misunderstanding how labellers work. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Since [a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) is not included, have a look [here](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/label_bquote.html). I'm positive it's related to your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to run both codes but got error that `object 'tss_profiles' not found`.

Therefore I can just hypothesise that you should remove quotes from the subscript text (`[20]` instead of what you have - `["20"]`).